# UIButton setTitleColor with RGB values not working

Tags: iphone

I  Have to set Title color for ffe1b1 to a UIButton.RGB value of ffe1b1 is 255,225,177.
I am trying this code, but its not properly reflect. I search on net Color components are floats between 0.0 and 1.0 !
So what is proper way for giving That RGB Values.Thanks

```
   UIButton *btn   = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] ; 
btn.frame = CGRectMake(134.0, 193.0, 80.0, 30.0);


[btn setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitle:@"Contact" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:225.0 blue:177.0 alpha:0.6 ]forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Just a guess: Have you tried dividing your values by 256.0 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the line like this

```
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:225.0 blue:177.0 alpha:0.6 ]forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

to

```
[btn setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0/255) green:(225.0/255) blue:(177.0/255) alpha:0.6 ]forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

in objective c you cannot directly use RGB values. follow this link:
http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/web-color-to-uicolor-convertor/